# Getting started with OpenCVForAndroid

Tags: android, opencv, awk, android-ndk, gnu-make

I am doing the prerequisite setup to get started with OpenCV for Android. The [OpenCV site for Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) says that I need a few things:

```
JDK

Android SDK and NDK

Eclipse IDE

ADT and CDT plugins for Eclipse
```

I need NDK and CDT only as I already have the rest. So I proceed to NDK [on this site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Reqs). I found that it also needs a few more things.
`CygWin`, `GNU AWK` and `GNU Make`

I could install CYGWin but I do not know how to install the other two. Can someone please help me with that ?

Comment: Use the cygwin installer to install awk and make

Comment: @krsteeve Can you please tell me how ? :) I am on win 7 32 bit

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows how to use the installer. Search for awk and make at step 6: http://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~aamodt/ece242/cygwin.html

Comment: @krsteeve I found Make. I couldn;t find AWK or NAWK. Are they in a different package ?